# Cut-off frequencies for image band pass filtering

Tags: image-processing, filtering

Does anyone know a way to define cut-off frequencies for band-pass filter based on the image pattern, i.e. based on the size and spacing in the structure of prevalent patch of the image?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the term frequency in the context of images really denote the general frequency as in time series signal?

Comment: Image can be interpreted as a two-dimensional signal therefore standard signal processing techniques are applicable, including Fourier transform where from spatial domain we go to frequency domain. So mathematically speaking it is the same as for a signal, but the meaning behind it is a bit different. I found a good discussion on it here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103608/what-does-the-fourier-transform-mean-in-the-context-of-images